# How do you send a json object to php backend properly

Tags: c#

While using something like this

"

```cs
 Dictionary<string, string> form = new Dictionary<string, string>
  {
      {_metajson, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(metaJson)}
  };
  HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(form));
```

However on the php side of things with `$_Request` I get the string and all the quotes are turned into `&#34;` so the json looks like

`{&#34;name&#34;:&#34;myname&#34;}`

Is there a better way to send json to a php backend?

On the PHP end of things I am simply assigning the json which has now lost the quotes and has weird marks with

```php
$json = $_REQUEST["test"];
```

The json I am sending is in memory, its not saved to a file anywhere. It is very small like shown above and is needed for the purposes of the application I am writing.

Comment: Where is PHP part in your question?

Comment: @biesior I was curious if there was a special way to receive json that is not a file through php. I looked but it seems sending json as a parameter is causing the quote marks to be turned into that special character signature.

Answer (score 0):

Use `php://input`

> `php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body.

Example:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('php://input');

//Converting It to PHP object:

$data = json_decode($json_string );
```

Comment: I have other parameters that are also sent with the request so this doesn't work. It is the same as using `json_encode(get_object_vars($_REQUEST));` Using the code above I get `%7B%22name%22%3A%22myname%22%7D` which is a whole other issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was just working with the same problem and here is my solution, it works for me

```
$data = $_POST['json'] ;
$json = json_decode($data, true);
echo json_encode($json);
```

afterwards, you can take the $json variable an do whatever you want to do with it

Comment: I have tried this, since the json comes in with all those special characters `&#34;` instead of quote marks the json_decode return is null.

Comment: Give this one a try : $data = json_decode(stripslashes(file_get_contents("php://input")));. You can use other functions to remove other characters as well. This one replaces slashes

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the approach which worked very well

I simply base64 encoded the json to avoid http changing special characters to odd string formats like `"` to `&#34;` and what not.

C# side - using this string in the dictionary form

```cs
string encodedJson = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(metaJson)));
```

PHP side

```php
$encoded_input  = $_REQUEST["metajson"];

$base64_decoded_input = base64_decode($encoded_input, true);
if (!$base64_decoded_input)
{
    // error out
}
$meta_json = json_encode(json_decode($base64_decoded_input));
```